# How to set initialState from Shared preferences?

Tags: redux, dart, flutter, sharedpreferences

I've been trying to add redux to my flutter app

I want to set MaterialUi theme based on user shared preferences

```
void main() {
  final store = Store<AppState>(
    reducer,
    initialState: AppState.initialState(),
  );

  runApp(MyApp(store: store));
}
```

I have this Function which returns what user preferences are

```
  static Future<String> getActiveTheme() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getString(_activeTheme) ?? "Light";
  }
```

and my AppState looks like this

```
class AppState {
  String theme;
  User user;

  AppState(this.theme, this.user);

  AppState.initialState()
      : theme = 'Light',
        user = null;
}
```

I would want instead of `theme: 'Light'` to get `theme: getActiveTheme()`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should consider an initialisation state where you can fetch this `String` and await for it, before passing it to the AppState

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is load the theme as part of your `main` method. You can then pass the theme you've loaded into your `AppState` constructors. Not that I've added `async` to your `main` method, and moved the setting of `theme` on your `AppState` to the parameters.

```
void main() async {

  var theme = await getActiveTheme();

  final store = Store<AppState>(
    reducer,
    initialState: AppState.initialState(theme),
  );

  runApp(MyApp(store: store));
}

class AppState {

  // ...

  AppState.initialState(this.theme)
      : user = null;
}
```